# Qué son headers .hpp en C++ y para qué sirven?

Tags: c++

Descubrí en un curso C++ para principiantes que no es necesario utilizar solamente los ficheros `.cpp` y que podemos utilizar `.hpp`.

Pero el profesor no ha explicado para qué sirven estos ficheros.

Entonces, ¿qué son headers `.hpp` en C++ y para qué sirven?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> #### Entonces qué son headers .hpp en C++ y para qué sirven?

Las cabeceras (headers) del lenguaje C tienen extensión `.h` (header). Como C++ es otro lenguaje se decidió usar una extensión diferente que sería `.hpp` (header plus plus).

Pero es una elección arbitraria, puedes usar la extensión que te plazca para cabeceras; siempre y cuando el compilador sea capaz de leer e interpretar el contenido de un archivo, la cabecera será indiferente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "Ejercicio1.txt"
#include "Patatas.fritas"
#include "no_tengo_extension"

int main() { return 0; }
```

Te puedo asegurar que si los archivos `Ejercicio1.txt`, `Patatas.fritas` y `no_tengo_extension` existen, cualquier compilador de C++ los aceptará.

Answer (score 7):

A la hora de estructurar un código en C++ puedes optar por poner todo el código en un único fichero:

fichero1

```
#include <iostream>

void func(int var)
{
  std::cout << var*2;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "fichero1"

int main()
{
  func(3);
}
```

Esta solución plantea varios problemas que se hacen evidentes cuando el proyecto empieza a crecer en tamaño:

- Cada modificación del fichero conlleva una recompilación de todos los ficheros que lo incluyan, lo cual puede dilatar el proceso de compilación durante varios minutos o incluso horas.
- Resolver las dependencias mutuas se torna complicado. El siguiente código, por ejemplo, no compilará:

ficheroA

```
#pragma once
#include "ficheroB"

struct A
{
  void func(B* b)
  { b->func1(); }

  void func1()
  { std::cout << "A\n"; }
};
```

ficheroB

```
#pragma once
#include "ficheroA"

struct B
{
  void func(A* a)
  { a->func1(); }

  void func1()
  { std::cout << "B\n"; }
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "ficheroA"
#include "ficheroB"

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;

  a->func(b);
  b->func(a);
}
```

**Nota:** He optado por usar `#pragma once` aunque no sea estándar para meter la menor cantidad de decoración al código.

Para solventar estos dos problemas podemos optar por dividir las funciones y las clases en dos (definición e implementación):

- definición: Es la parte pública o cabecera e indica la interfaz de la función o clase.
- implementación: Es la parte privada. Aquí se incluye el código fuente.

El ejemplo anterior debidamente adaptado:

ficheroA

```
#pragma once

class B;

struct A
{
  void func(B* b);

  void func1();
};
```

ficheroA.cpp

```
#include "ficheroA"
#include "ficheroB"

void A::func(B* b)
{ b->func1(); }

void A::func1()
{ std::cout << "A\n"; }
```

ficheroB

```
#pragma once

class A;

struct B
{
  void func(A* a);

  void func1();
};
```

ficheroB.cpp

```
#include "ficheroA"
#include "ficheroB"

void B::func(A* a)
{ a->func1(); }

void B::func1()
{ std::cout << "B\n"; }
```

Al separar la declaración de la implementación se ha conseguido resolver la interdependencia (la dependencia se ha movido al fichero de implementación, del que no depende ningún otro fichero) y el código ahora sí puede ser compilado.

Así pues las cabeceras se usarán para indicar la interfaz de las clases y funciones, quedando el código fuente relegado a los ficheros de implementación.

**Nota:** Las funciones `inline`, `constexpr` y `template` deben alojar la implementación en la cabecera ya que las limitaciones actuales impiden que el compilador pueda localizar su implementación en un fichero de código fuente.