# error en <iostream.h> DEV C++

Tags: c++

Al momento de compilar mi código me sale un error

> "NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY"

Lo marca en la línea de `<iostream.h>`. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar a solucionarlo?

Comment: Las cabeceras propias del estándar de C++ vienen **sin extensión**. es `#include <iostream>`

Answer (score 5):

`iostream.h`, es una librería pre-estandarización de C++, en 1998.

No creo que hoy en día siga habiendo muchas plataformas que la soporten, pero sí es posible encontrarla en código *legacy*.
Después de la estandarización, las librerías estándar no llevan h, en este caso, la librería adecuada sería `<iostream>`.
Como regla general, no deberías incluir ninguna librería estándar con `.h`.
Para incluir librerías de C, utiliza las nuevas versiones, que encapsulan el código en el namespace `std`.
Por ejemplo : `<stdio.h>` -> `<ctsdio>`,`<stdlib.h>` -> `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: Interesante el detalle histórico, no lo conocía. Tal vez valga la pena hablar de las diferencias entre las cabeceras de [tag:c] y [tag:c++] que puede consultarse [en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48268/librerias-de-c-y-c/48305#48305). También una corta mención a las extensiones de las cabeceras comentado [en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52140/qu%c3%a9-son-headers-hpp-en-c-y-para-qu%c3%a9-sirven/52145#52145).

Answer (score 2):

Los archivos de la cabecera estándar de C++ [no llevan extensión](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream). Intenta esto:

```
#include <iostream>
```